# how can I take average pf several row by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get the average of the following

```
df<- structure(list(data1 = c(207.404, 212.581, 880.965, 1033.05, 
296.026, 2198.92, 2422.49, 1796.63, 2272.94, 2256.56, 3359.57, 
3674.91, 3133.45, 3510.23, 3651.04, 2816.53, 2681.64, 2894.54, 
2689.13, 2828.89), data2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), data3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("HH1", "HH2", "HH3", "HH4", "HH5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("data1", 
"data2", "data3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L
))
```

I do the following

```
df %>% 
group_by(data2) %>%
summarise_at(vars(-data3), funs(mean(.)))
```

but there is a problem which I cannot understand if I am doing it right or not

lets do this manually and see if it gives the same answer

for example for the first one

```
mean(207.404,212.581, 880.965, 1033.050 ,296.026)
```

the answer is 207.404 while in the above script it calculates 526

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `mean(c(207.404,212.581, 880.965, 1033.050 ,296.026))`. `mean` takes a vector of values as its first argument. `mean(207.404,212.581, 880.965, 1033.050 ,296.026)` is using only the first value.

Comment: @eipi10 you are right, souds like a dumb question :-) thanks i think it is ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `dplyr`. The base R `mean` function takes its first argument as a vector. When you provide more than one vectors, only the first one would be evaluated. See the following example.

```
mean(c(207.404,212.581, 880.965, 1033.050 ,296.026))
# [1] 526.0052
```